# How to print variable in catch block?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm newbie to programming. Help me out. I want to print the value of links which fails in try block to catch block. How could I do that? Here is my code :

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException {
        try { 
            int i=1;
            String links[]= new String[10];
            links[1]="link1"
            links[2]="link2"
            links[3]="link3"
            links[3]="link4"
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            while(i<5){
                driver.get(links[i])
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'image')]")).click();
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            // e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume one of the links fails to find an element. I want that link to be printed in catch block and go to next link. How could I do that?

Comment: I've corrected the compilation error in your code with the additional closing brace after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to try the next link after a link fails, you should put the try-catch block inside the while loop.

```
int i=0;
String links[]= new String[10];
links[0]="link1";
links[1]="link2";
links[2]="link3";
links[3]="link4";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

while(i<4){
    try { 
        driver.get(links[i]);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'image')]")).click();
        i++;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println(links[i] + " failed");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hideandseek `i` is declared in the first line of the snippet. Perhaps you copied the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

To have access to your variables in both the `try` and `catch` blocks you need to move their scope further out (in your case to the surrounding method). If you want to be able to continue iterating on your array, you need to make sure that you catch your exception within a single iteration of your loop, by moving the try-catch block inside of it. This also shrinks the size of the try-catch block, which is generally a good thing.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException {
        int i = 1;
        String links[] = new String[10];
        links[1] = "link1"
        links[2] = "link2"
        links[3] = "link3"
        links[3] = "link4"
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        while (i < 5) {
            try {
                driver.get(links[i])
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'image')]")).click();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Problem link had index: " + i);
            } finally {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Edd the finally block is much better style than the double increment from the other answer... +1

Answer (score 0):

Declare the links variable out of the try block. The link variable is out of scope in your code i.e. it should be before you start the try block.

```
String links[] = new String[10]
try{...

}
```